How to Set Neovim as the Default Editor in Midnight Commander on Windows (CMD in Windows Terminal)?
Following this question, I'm trying to configure Midnight Commander (MC) on Windows (running mc.exe in CMD within Windows Terminal) to use Neovim (nvim), all installed via Chocolatey and the containing folder of the below executables are added to the PATH environment variables:
C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\nvim.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe

as the default editor instead of Notepad.
I've tried a few approaches, but MC keeps defaulting to Notepad, and it fails to handle file paths with spaces correctly. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Disabled the built-in viewer/editor:
In MC, I went to F9 > Options > Configuration and unchecked "Use internal edit" and "Use internal view."

Set the EDITOR environment variable:
As suggested here, before launching MC, I used:
set "EDITOR=nvim mc"


Modified mc.ext:
As suggested here, I added the following lines to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Midnight Commander\mc.ext:
# Default target for anything not described above
default/*
    Open= %var{EDITOR:nvim} "%f" &
    Edit= %var{EDITOR:nvim} "%f" &

I also tried another format under include/editor:
include/editor
    Open=%var{EDITOR:nvim} "%f"



However, MC still opens Notepad instead of Neovim and doesn't handle paths with spaces correctly.
My Questions:

Is there a way to make MC on Windows recognize Neovim as the default editor for certain file types?
How can I ensure MC handles file paths with spaces in CMD?


"set "EDITOR=nvim mc"" Shouldn't it be just  set "EDITOR=nvim" ? export EDITOR=vim works for me on Linux; I'm a long-time (since 1995) user of MC.

"…added to the PATH environment variables…" Add to %PATH% directoies, not paths to .exe: C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin and C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander

@phd Yeah, I phrased it wrongly and indeed I did not add the file to the PATH but just the containing directories.

so far I had a bit of success by adding the full path to the .exe to the mc.ext file Open="C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\nvim.exe" "%f" & and Edit="C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\nvim.exe" "%f" & so now it opens in nvim when the path has no spaces in it, but hangs when there is one!

In Linux in mc.ext, menu and other files it's recommended to use %f/%s and all other placeholders without quotes because mc escape them itself before passing to shell. May be it's true on w32? Try Edit=nvim %f

@phd OK then. That could be very much the problem. Is there a way to instruct mc not to scape the double quotation marks? Or write a cmd batch or PowerShell script that can handle  paths with spaces in them?

"Is there a way to instruct mc not to scape the double quotation marks?" No AFAIK. %f should be ok. Tried it?
